# Assign the row number in PLSQL for the user entered input in the Business Objects screen

Tags: sql, plsql, business-objects

I am using SQL query against Oracle database and its get the input from Business Objects.

Example:

```
SELECT EMP_NUM from table1 Where EMP_NUM IN (@PROMPT VALUE,MULTI)
```

i.e in Business Objects screen, user can enter multiple value like 222 and then 999 and then 888. 
Finally they click submit. In the BO screen then it displaying the ACCT_NUM properly.

i.e the above query translated like below.

```
SELECT EMP_NUM from table1 Where EMP_NUM IN ('222','999','888')
```

So the Business Object passes input like '222','999','888'.

What i need is row number should be assigned for these value as like below.

```
Row_num  EMP_NUM

1          222
2          999
3          888
```

i.e I need the row number to be assigned in the order user entered in the BO screen.

I thought concatenating the string and from there i can use REGEX to split the string and assign row number.
Like:

```
CONCAT(@PROMPT VALUE,MULTI)
```

But this operator will concatenate only 2 strings. In the above case its 3 input and even user can enter multiple inputs. I can't use `||` operator because BO just replaces the PROMPT variable with values like below.

```
CONCAT('222','999','888')
```

I need alternative solution. How can I assign row number for this scenario?

Comment: why don't you try using `ROW_NUMBER()` function ? LINK - [Standard docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm)

Comment: Please show us your complete stored procedure

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() function will give result based on table. But i need the row number based on the input given

Comment: We are using derived table.  Its just a display the input given by the business user in the way it shows above.                                                                                             what i need is, is there is a way to  '222','999','888' i can concatenate this string(even it is having more inputs the solution should work).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting requirement.  This is how I would implement it:

First, in the database, create a new user-defined table datatype:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_varray AS TABLE OF varchar2(50);
```

(the width should be the same as your emp_num column)

Next create a function that will return the index of an element within a table of t_array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION index_of (i_varray t_varray,i_text VARCHAR2) 
RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
    FOR n IN 1..i_varray.count
    LOOP
        IF i_varray(n) = i_text THEN
            RETURN n;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

To test:

```
select index_of(t_varray('abc','def','ghi'),'def') from dual
```

returns:
`2`, which is the position of "def" in the provided list.

Next, in the universe, create a new dimension:

```
index_of(t_varray@Prompt('Select values','A','Array Test\Text',Multi,Constrained),ARRAY_TEST.TEXT)
```

(the text within the @Prompt should be a copy of what you are currently using in your filter.  In my example, the object containing the LOV is named "Text" in the "Array Test" class, and the column I'm referencing is array_test.text.  If you're using IDT, you can use Parameters and and LOV; I'm not doing that here for simplicity)

(No, there really is no left parenthesis after t_varray.  It looks weird but it will work)

Finally, add the new object to the report query, along with the original filter with the prompt.  In my test the generated SQL is:

```
SELECT
  index_of(t_varray@Prompt('Select values','A','Array Test\Text',Multi,Constrained),ARRAY_TEST.TEXT),
  ARRAY_TEST.TEXT,
  ARRAY_TEST.ID
FROM
  ARRAY_TEST
WHERE
  ( ARRAY_TEST.TEXT IN @Prompt('Select values','A','Array Test\Text',Multi,Constrained)  )
```

Running the report and selecting "ghi" and "abc" in the prompt produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT
  index_of(t_varray('ghi','abc'),ARRAY_TEST.TEXT),
  ARRAY_TEST.TEXT,
  ARRAY_TEST.ID
FROM
  ARRAY_TEST
WHERE
  ( ARRAY_TEST.TEXT IN ('ghi','abc')  )
```

...which produces:

```
1 ghi 32
2 abc  2
```

(the 32 and 2 are just random IDs I added for completeness)

(Note the rendering of the call to t_array -- it now has the proper parentheses, which were provided by @prompt() )

Running again, selecting "def", "abc", "ghi":

```
1 def 50
2 abc  2
3 ghi 32
```

If you *want*, you can remove the filter from the query and leave the newly-created dimension.  This will return all data, but sorted according to the order of the prompt.

Credit to [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/137219/function-variable-number-of-arguments-plsql) for inspiration.